# Finding minimum in 2D array C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, min

So I have this program to take in an integer(i) and then make a 2D array i x i
and that part I can get to work fine, but now I am trying to find the smallest number in the array and this is always returning 0.

```
int smallest_number(int b[MAXrow][MAXcol], int n)
{
    int min = b[0][0];
    int x,y;

    for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {

        for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
        {
            if (min > b[x][y])
            {
                min = b[x][y];

            }

        }
    }
return min; 
}
```

Comment: Copy-paste your code in instead of typing it out; perhaps the "real" code has more errors that didn't make it through to this post. Also, show the code that you are calling this function with.   I suspect that if `MAXrow` and `MAXcol` are different then using `n` for both dimensions is not right.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the "min" variable too soon. Currently, it is in the outer loop. What you want is to have it outside of the other loop.

Like this:

```
int smallest_number(int b[MAXrow][MAXcol], int n)
{
   int min = b[0][0];
   int x,y;

   for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
   {
       for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
       {
           if (min > b[x][y])
           {
               min = b[x][y];
           }
       } 
   }  

   return min;
}
```

Comment: Oops. That's actually how it is written in my code, I messed it up when copying it. Either way it is still returning 0.

Comment: No worries. Some questions: **1.)** Is it possible that 0 is the minimum number? **2.)** Are you sure that the 2d array is size 'n' in both the x and y direction?

Comment: I actually figured it out, in my main function I just called the function but i didn't set minimum to equal what the function returned. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try code below to find maximum & minimum from a matrix of any order.

Code :

#include<stdio.h>

void acc(int [5][5],int,int );
void maxmin(int [5][5],int,int);

void main()
{
    int a[5][5],r,c;   

    printf("\n\t\t**Smallest & largest no. from matrix**\n"); 

    printf("\n\tEnter the size of row:\n\t");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("\tEnter the size of column:\n\t");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    acc(a,r,c);
    maxmin(a,r,c);
}

void acc(int m[5][5],int r,int c)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\n\tenter the elements of matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("\telement[%d][%d]=  ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&m[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void maxmin(int m[5][5],int r, int c)
{
    int max=m[0][0], min=m[0][0],i,j;

    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<c; j++)
        {   
            if(m[i][j]>max)
                max= m[i][j];

            if(m[i][j]<min)
                min= m[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tGreatest no. is :  %d\n",max);
    printf("\n\tSmallest no. is :  %d\n",min);
}
```